# Combine string and OBJECT ID

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I would like to update the Map_Feature_ID field with a String " WP_" and then follow the "WP_" with the OBJECTID field.

So I will end up with **"WP_1", "WP_2**" all the way to the end in the Map Feature ID field.

I am not sure if there is a way to do it with a python script or should I use the field calculator instead?

[image: Map_Feature_ID update]

Answer (score 4):

Just try in python in filed calculator as below-

```
"WP_" + str(!OBJECTID!)
```

N.B. The field going to be populated also needs to be string/text

Answer (score 0):

```
update_field = 'Map_Feature_ID'
expression = '"WP_{}".format(!OBJECTID!)'

arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature_class, update_field, expression, 'PYTHON')
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000